# Minimum value using Log Axis in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have the next code

```
<mx:LineChart id="LEChart" width="900" height="600" 
                          showDataTips="true"  showAllDataTips="false"  
                          rollOver="lineChart_rollOver(event)"
                          rollOut="lineChart_rollOut(event)">                                       
                <!-- vertical axis -->
                <mx:verticalAxis>
                    <mx:LinearAxis title="U/Uratedd" minimum="0.50" maximum="1.50"/>
                </mx:verticalAxis>

                <mx:horizontalAxis>
                    <mx:LogAxis id="LE70" interval="10" minimum="1000"  maximum="1.0E7" title="Life expectancy(h)"/>
                </mx:horizontalAxis>

                <!--<mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
                    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{LE70}" canDropLabels="true"/>
                </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>-->                                        

                <mx:series>
                    <mx:LineSeries dataProvider="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.arrLE70}" yField="zx" xField="fx" form="curve" displayName="Profit"/>
                    <mx:LineSeries dataProvider="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.arrLE85}" yField="zx" xField="fx" form="curve" />
                </mx:series>    

            </mx:LineChart> 
            <mx:Legend dataProvider="{LEChart}" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
```

I need the minimum value be 1000 but It's impossible to get it.

Please, any idea?

http://subefotos.com/ver/?e9e23ef45417b02a7f7f5bd582574788o.png

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: I've just add a snapshot. I need that the 1000 value be the first value in the x axis. In my graphic you can see the first value is 100. I don't know why?

Comment: Try changing your LogAxis maximum to something like 10000 and see what happens.

Comment: I get the same problem.  http://subefotos.com/ver/?2985b4b83a52381af36bcbace464bceao.png  I use the 1000000 value.